# App.Config for different environments

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have not worked much on configs. I have 5 environments, env1,env2,env3,env4 and PROD.I have an **App.config** file and also have App.Debug.config, App.ENV1.config,App.ENV2.config,App.ENV3.config,App.ENV4.config and App.Release.config. My problem is that each environment instead of reading its own env specific file, reads the App.Config. 
This is what I have for ENV1.

```
<Target Name="ENV1" DependsOnTargets="">
<Exec Command="powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File .\UpdateWebConfig.ps1" />

<MSBuild Projects="$(ApplicationProjectFile)"
           Properties="Configuration=ENV1;DeployOnBuild=True;PublishProfile=devscenmgrapp1;VisualStudioVersion=11.0" />

<Message Text="Clean project:" />
<MSBuild Projects="$(WpfApplicationProjectFile)" Properties="Configuration=ENV1" Targets="Clean"/>
<MSBuild Projects="$(WpfApplicationProjectFile)" Properties="Configuration=ENV1;Install=false;BootstrapperEnabled=false;GenerateManifests=true" Targets="Publish"/>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjLocation Include="..\Source\DocGen.UI.TemplateDesignerWPF" />
  <ProjLocationReleaseDir Include="%(ProjLocation.Identity)\bin\ENV1"/>
  <ProjPublishLocation Include="%(ProjLocationReleaseDir.Identity)\app.publish"/>
  <DeploymentFolder Include="\\devscenmgrapp1\c$\InetPub\wwwroot\DocGen\Wpf"/>
  <SetupFiles Include="%(ProjPublishLocation.Identity)\*.*"/>
  <UpdateFiles Include="%(ProjPublishLocation.Identity)\Application Files\**\*.*"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Copy SourceFiles="@(SetupFiles)" DestinationFolder="\\devscenmgrapp1\c$\InetPub\wwwroot\DocGen\Wpf\" />
<Copy SourceFiles="@(UpdateFiles)" DestinationFolder="\\devscenmgrapp1\c$\InetPub\wwwroot\DocGen\Wpf\Application Files\%(RecursiveDir)" />

<Copy SourceFiles="@(LicenseFile)" DestinationFolder="\\devscenmgrapp1\c$\InetPub\wwwroot\DocGen\bin" />
```

What am I missing here, due to which the ENV1 points to App.Config and not the App.ENV1.Config?

Comment: When you publish the project (because alternate config files are only used on publishing, not building) you specify the environment as the build target configuration. Then Visual Studio merges the contents of the specified file into app config, which the app then uses. So when you publish a RELEASE version, the App.Release.config is merged into the base app.config, forming the app.config for the release version. The alternate files are never read directly by the app.

Comment: @stuartd  Thanks.So its the merging which is conflicting. In App.config's  <appSettings>  I have this: <add key="ServiceEnvironment" value="http://project"/>. But in App.ENV1.config <appSettings>  I have this: <add key="ServiceEnvironment" value="http://projectENV1"/>. I guess due to the merging somehow, ENV1 points to http://project instead of http://projectENV1